# Hibernate Search: corrupted index after persisting new Entity

Tags: hibernate-search

I am trying to insert new Entity in my database with Hibernate, the problem is that the Index that should be automatically created by Hibernate search is now throwing AssertionFailure Exception when I search for it.

For example: by searching for csCaseNumber=5 I get this list of results:[55,557,565] which is correct. But after I persist new Entity with csCaseNumber=511 and then search for csCaseNumber=5 again I get AssertionFailure Exception.

But by searching for csCaseNumber=51 I get the correct answer which is [511],
and the only way to get all results correctly is by reindexing everything manually.

The id fild is beeing analysed by this custom analyzer

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@AnalyzerDef(name = "CustomAutocompleteAnalyzer",
        tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = WhitespaceTokenizerFactory.class), 
        filters = { 
            @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
            @TokenFilterDef(factory = EdgeNGramFilterFactory.class, params = {
                @Parameter(name = "minGramSize", value = "1"),
                @Parameter(name = "maxGramSize", value = "10")
    }), 
    })
@Table(name = "table")
@XmlRootElement

public class Table implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id")
    private BigDecimal id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "cs_case_number")
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO
           , analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "CustomAutocompleteAnalyzer")
    )
    private String csCaseNumber;

    public BigDecimal getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(BigDecimal id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getCsCaseNumber() {
        return csCaseNumber;
    }

    public void setCsCaseNumber(String csCaseNumber) {
        this.csCaseNumber = csCaseNumber;
    }
  @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof TCase)) {
            return false;
        }
        TCase other = (TCase) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.luceneproject.pojo.TCase[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

the Method that persist new Entity

```
    public void addNewFall() {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("com.luceneProject_LuceneProject_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU");

        if (fallNummer2 != null && fallId != 0) {
            EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            try {
                BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(fallId);
                TCase tcase = new TCase();
                tcase.setId(bd);
                tcase.setCsCaseNumber(fallNummer2);


                em.persist(tcase);
                em.getTransaction().commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            } finally {
                em.close();
                emf.close();
            }
        }

    }
```

The Error message

```
Info:   --------- com.luceneproject.luceneproject.FallLazyDataModel@f6fe5ee -----------------
Severe:   Error Rendering View[/table2.xhtml]
org.hibernate.search.exception.AssertionFailure: An entity got loaded even though it was not part of the EntityInfo list
    at org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.CriteriaObjectInitializer.initializeObjects(CriteriaObjectInitializer.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.MultiClassesQueryLoader.executeLoad(MultiClassesQueryLoader.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.AbstractLoader.load(AbstractLoader.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.FullTextQueryImpl.doHibernateSearchList(FullTextQueryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.FullTextQueryImpl.list(FullTextQueryImpl.java:225)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.FullTextQueryImpl.getResultList(FullTextQueryImpl.java:124)
    at com.luceneproject.luceneproject.DataService.getListfromLucene(DataService.java:168)
    at com.luceneproject.luceneproject.DataService.getFallsList(DataService.java:49)
    at com.luceneproject.luceneproject.FallLazyDataModel.load(FallLazyDataModel.java:30)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.loadLazyData(DataTable.java:573)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.FilterFeature.encode(FilterFeature.java:140)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:949)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1912)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:638)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:874)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1747)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:395)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1747)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1747)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1747)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1747)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:423)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:342)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:63)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1124)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1905)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:465)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:194)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:126)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:223)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:671)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:550)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:199)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I am using Hibernate Search version 5.11

Comment: We'll need the code of your entity, with all the Hibernate Search annotations. The document id is not analyzed by Hibernate Search, so I assume you have a separate field called "id" that is not the document ID?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, i did update my post with Entity Class

Comment: Ok, apparently it has nothing to do with the ID. Can you show us the code of your query? And maybe also the value of your `hibernate.search.` configuration properties? Also, please re-throw the exceptions in `addNewFall`: indexing may be failing and you didn't notice it because the exception was ignored.